# Why can't I set my long long variable to 1e18 + 10?

Tags: c++

I have implemented a program in C++ and it showed a very strange bug.
First of all, if I assigned my variable a like this: long long a = 1e9 + 10 and then print the value of a, it ran correctly. But if I set a to 1e18 + 10 and then print the value of a, it showed that a equals 10^18 only. Can anyone help me with this? I tried a lot but I can't understand why. Thanks.
This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    long long a = 1e9 + 10;
    cout << a << endl;
    a = 1e18 + 10;
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ec2Szn` shouldn't be your code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a proper [mre] (copy-pasted, as text, into the question itself).

Comment: Also note that integers in C++ doesn't have `e` syntax. `1e9` is a **`double`** floating point value.

Comment: `1e18 + 10` gives the same result as `1e18`, because the calculation will happen in floating-point numbers which [are not arbitrarily precise](https://0.30000000000000004.com/). It doesn't matter that you are *going to* assign the result to a `long long`; the calculation happens first. The compiler should warn you about the loss of precision.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Only MSVC warns about that, but that's just their regular warning about assigning `double` to `int`: https://godbolt.org/z/eddrfrPhr

Answer (score 4):

`1e18` is a value having type `double`. The presicion of type `double` is typically around 15 decimal digits, so adding `10` to `1e18` may not change the value of `double`.

You can add a cast to `long long` before addition to eliminate the issue in this case, but generally you should avoid using floating-point numbers to deal with integers.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    long long value = static_cast<long long>(1e18) + 10;
    std::cout << value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now I can understand it a little bit. By the way this is my first time posting a question on Stackoverflow so I have read the induction in the wrong way and accidentally used ec2Szn as my code. Sorry for that.